# How to solve expectation like the following type: $E(E(X|Y))$ and $E(P(X|Y))$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I am reading relation between correlation and independence from the wiki: [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent)

In the site I linked above, I got challenged.

---

Definition of random variables $X, W, Y$:

\begin{align}X&\sim N(0,1)\\P(W=-1)&= P(W=1)=0.5\\Y&=WX\end{align}

---

$
\begin{align}
\mbox{cov}(X,Y)&=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)=E(XY)=E(E(XY|W))\\
&=E(X^2)\mbox{Pr}(W=1)+E(-X^2)\mbox{Pr}(W=-1)\\
&=1\cdot\frac12 + (-1)\cdot \frac12 = 0
\end{align}
$

1. $E(E(XY|W)) \longrightarrow E(X^2)\mbox{Pr}(W=1)+E(-X^2)\mbox{Pr}(W=-1)$ ?

---

$\begin{align}
\mbox{Pr}(Y\le X)&=E(\mbox{Pr}(Y\le x|W))\\
&=\mbox{Pr}(X\le x)\mbox{Pr}(W=1) + \mbox{Pr}(-X \le x)\mbox{Pr}(W = -1)\\
&=\Phi(x)\frac12 + \Phi(x)\frac12 = \Phi(x)
\end{align}$

where $\Phi(x)$ is the ***c.d.f.*** of the normal distribution.

2. $E(\mbox{Pr}(Y\le x|W)) \longrightarrow \mbox{Pr}(X\le x)\mbox{Pr}(W=1) + \mbox{Pr}(-X \le x)\mbox{Pr}(W = -1)$ ?

---

Can someone explain 1 and 2? I want to know its process omitted.

Comment: "how it is possible to change, 1 and 2" What does that mean? What is your doubt?

Comment: @leonbloy I changed my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1.) : In general, $E(XY|W)$ is a random variable that depends on the conditioning variable. That is, $E(XY|W)=g(W)$.

Also, in general, you know that $E(A)=\sum a \,  p(A=a)$ and $E(g(A))=\sum g(a) \,  p(A=a)$

Then $E[E(XY|W)]=E[g(W)]=\sum g(w) P(W=w)$. But in our case $W$ can take two values, hence $$E[E(XY|W)]= g(1) P(W=1)+g(-1) P(W=-1) $$

Concretely, $g(1)=E(X Y|W=1)= E(X\, X\, W | W=1) =E(X^2)$, etc

For (2.) : It's the same thing. Now the function is $g(W)=\mbox{Pr}(Y\le x|W)$

Comment: Very concise. The key idea is $E[\mbox{something}|W] = g(W)$. I got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Because I am studying digital communication and stochastic processes myself, I posted many questions. I'm so sorry always posting questions without answering. :(

Comment: Note that E(E(Z|W))=E(Z) in full generality.